# add second axis that is unique to each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I often use a second y-axis to show summary stats like the mean of a distribution. In this case how can I limit the values shown on the upper y-axis so that only the mean for a respective facet is displayed rather than all means being displayed on each facet?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

means_by_cyl <- 
    mtcars |> 
    summarise(mean_wt = mean(wt) |> round(1), .by=cyl)

mtcars |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = wt)) +
    geom_density() +
    facet_grid(. ~ cyl, labeller = label_both) +
    scale_x_continuous(
    sec.axis =
        dup_axis(
            breaks = means_by_cyl$mean_wt,
            name = "Means"
            )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think a simple `sec.axis` can be facet-dependent, the only way they can "vary" is when `scales="free"` is set, but that doesn't do what you want. My suggestion is to look at annotations, or perhaps glue three independent plots together (e.g., `patchwork` or `cowplot`).

Comment: Have a look at the `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales`. See [Controlling the labels on the primary and secondary axis with facet_wrap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024630/controlling-the-labels-on-the-primary-and-secondary-axis-with-facet-wrap/71024945#71024945) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can try using `ggh4x`. Here the data.frame of means are ordered by `cyl`. The `facet_grid2` includes "free_x" so the x-axis scales can vary. The `facetted_pos_scales` allows for different breaks for each facet plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

means_by_cyl <- mtcars |> 
  summarise(mean_wt = mean(wt) |> round(1), .by=cyl) |>
  arrange(cyl)

mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = wt)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_grid2(. ~ cyl, labeller = label_both, scales = "free_x", independent = "x") +
  facetted_pos_scales(x = lapply(means_by_cyl$mean_wt, \(x)
                                 scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(breaks = x))))
```

**Plot**

[image: facet_grid with means on axis for each plot]